# how add Firebase on my react native project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm stuck on this step to install firebase on my project.

They ask me to copy that on my principal appdelegate. i have the choice between swift and objective-c but the code is not the same .

This is the objective-c code they asked me to add :
[image]

and this is my objective C code on my app delegate.m

[image]

Same for swift this is the code they asked to add

[image]

And also my code on my appdelegate.m in swift

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just do this two steps, don't worry about other codes.

1. At the top of the file, import the Firebase SDK after "#import "AppDelegate.h": #import <Firebase.h>
2. Within your existing didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, add the following before "return true" : [FIRApp configure];